# "No display of image in django when got access to aws s3 bucket"

Tags: python, django, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to display images in django from AWS S3 bucket. The image is not displaying, no error is shown.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

The display of image is expected in django profile but no display of any image, and no error is shown.

Comment: You don't give any info but your env variables. 
Show us what you're doing in your python code.
Can you access the image using your browser and the url?
Also Give us your bucket policies .

Comment: no i can't access using browser and the url

Comment: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0074591E75B57A16</RequestId>
<HostId>
jhasX1AX6JoQRVzlV+rkyl9JTlHwzyVQe1wi0GwFbrbAcWxDPDmXwJEB5sEHSguNmtboQ4U7+VE=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: What are the bucket policies? I'm kinda certain it's related to it since the error is an "Access Denied"

Comment: bucket has no policy

Comment: This is the reason why it fails.
Add a public read policy to your bucket.
Here's an example : https://www.devroom.io/2010/12/24/public-readable-amazon-s3-bucket-policy/